# Insert List of lists in a database Python

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite

I am trying to insert a list of lists in a database but i get this error "    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test VALUES(?, ?, ?)',list2)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 200 supplied."
in my list of lists there are 201 lists

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import pandas as pd
def Load():
    list1 = []
    comparar = []
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("Pruebas")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test ( "id" INT NOT NULL , "User" TEXT NOT NULL , "Followed" INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (id))')
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Test")
    list1 = cursor.fetchall()
    #print(data)    
    data = pd.read_csv(r'J:\\Proyectos y Trabajos\\Python\\Bot Instagram Follow\\Terminado BR\\Test.csv',delimiter=';')
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in data.values]
    
    for i in tuples:
        if i not in list1:
            list1.append(i)
    list2 = [list(elem) for elem in list1]
    
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Test") 
    conexion.commit() 
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test VALUES(?, ?, ?)',list2)
    conexion.commit() 
    conexion.close()
Load()
```

Comment: try `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test VALUES(?, ?, ?)',(list2,))` and let me know but can you also say `print(list2)` and include it with the Q

Comment: `VALUES(?, ?, ?)` means you're trying to insert three values.  Does `list2` have exactly three values?

Comment: I get this error now: File "j:/Proyectos y Trabajos/Python/Bot Instagram Follow/Terminado BR/app.py", line 23, in Load
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test VALUES(?, ?, ?)',(list2,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: List2 is a list of 201 lists and eachone have 3 values inside like this '[201, 'rodrigo_petrizzo', 0]'

Comment: That isn't how you insert it. One way would be to loop through the list and individually insert each piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `list2` and perform an insert on the values in each sub-list:

```
for sublist in list2:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test VALUES(?, ?, ?)', sublist)
connexion.commit()
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be `(sublist,)` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud No, I don't believe so.  `sublist,` is a sequence of one value, but you need a sequence of three values to match the three placeholder tokens.

Comment: Oh yes prolly you makes sense :D